# No message body writer found for class : class java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to consume a JAXRS endpoint. here is what I tried to make it work.

```
Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<String, String>();
variables.put("email", "sample@gmail.com");     
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
JSONProvider provider = new JSONProvider();
provider.setNamespaceMap(variables);
providers.add(provider);

WebClient plainAddClient = WebClient.create("http://hostname:portnumber/cxf/jaxrs/EmailService/subscriber/update", providers);
plainAddClient.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(variables);
```

when I try to run the above snippet, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportNoMessageHandler(AbstractClient.java:486) - .No message body writer found for class : class java.util.HashMap.
```

I have no clue whats going wrong with my approach. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like you're attempting to send json to the server but actually sending the HashMap instead? Is your message body correctly converted to json before sending it?

Maybe try to send plain json for testing

```
plainAddClient.accept("application/json")
 .type("application/json")
 .post({"email":"sample@gmail.com"})
```

Comment: you are right. I was able to resolve it y'day by just sending the plain json. I wish you had given me this suggestion yday and saved me a lot of trouble